# "export as runnable JAR" option is missing

Tags: java, eclipse

Literally the button is missing. I right click my project -> export -> ... There's only JAR file and Javadoc here.

What did I do wrong?

Edit: The program I'm using is Eclipse.

Comment: Copied from the about section. Version: 3.3.2
Build id: M20080221-1800

Comment: Wow. That's a 4 years and a half old version. You could use a newer one.

Comment: Ooh sh*t, I guess my lecturer is using old course literature or something. Thanks :D Will try this out asap but I assume it's going to work.

Comment: It's just an assignment from school. We're learning about making .jar files currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version of Eclipse.  The Export as Runnable Jar came around 3.4 or 3.5.

Comment: It took some time to download but it's working :D Thanks everyone.