# No Runnable JAR file option on the export window in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java application and want to create a runnable JAR file. I cannot see the runnable JAR file option on export dialog box in my eclipse. Do I need to download something or change the setting in order to see this option? If so, would you tell me how to do it. thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Java category and the regular Jar export wizard available? Can you show it missing?

Comment: What Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: @GGrec Eclipse Platform Version is 3.3.2

Comment: @nitind I added the screenshot of the export windows.

Comment: Try a newer version. R3.3.2 was 6 years ago, and it may very well have not even *had* that feature yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["export as runnable JAR" option is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805059/export-as-runnable-jar-option-is-missing)

Comment: @nitind I download the latest version and see the option. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a newer version. R3.3.2 was 6 years ago, and it may very well have not even had that feature yet.